# Python user input file path

Tags: python

I am working on an easy project which requires user input a path for program and goes to this path
Here, I Worte on OSX:

```
from pathlib import Path

def main():
    user_input_path = Path(input())
```

And debug like this

```
>>> /Users/akrios/Desktop/123
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You are entering a path in to the Python interpreter. Have you actually *called* `main()` anywhere?

Comment: If you add a prompt, you'll know when to type. Perhaps `user_input_path = Path(input("Input path: "))`.

Comment: I am new to Python. I though when I am debugging it, the only thing I need to do is F5 and function would have be called. Like when you finish a *.exe It is program and can be executed without calling your functions.

Comment: Yes, that's true if you're using an IDE like Eclipse

Comment: If you are using python 2 - you need to use raw_input for this.

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` function reads in the input, and then tries to parse it as if it's something in Python notation. Instead, use the `raw_input()` function, it does not parse anything and returns the input as a string.